# I have followed setup to the letter (updated Cocoapods, added plist file, added entitlements file), but getting this error:

Tags: swift, service, cocoapods, google-play-services

```
messagingapp[385:75539] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2018-01-05 01:58:22.494778+0530 messagingapp[385:75539] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2018-01-05 01:58:22.524336+0530 messagingapp[385:75434] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file name is "GoogleService-Info.plist". sometime, if you download multiple times the plist file, or if you did that for other projects, the file "GoogleService-Info1.plist" "GoogleService-Info2.plist" ... are created and it create an error. Make sure that the plist file has the right name.

Comment: You are welcome @taxideals . If my answer helped you for resolving your question, please make sure to validate my answer by the green check. Ty